# Ajax request in MVC doesn't return corresponding value to the HTML page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Below is my script in Dashboard module.

```
$(function()
{
    var o;
    $.get('dashboard/xhrgetInsert',function(o)
    {
            for(var i = 0;i <= o.length; i++)
            {
                $("#appendHere").append("<div>"+o[i].text+"</div>");
            }
    },'json');
    $("#randomInsert").submit(function()
    {
        alert("hi");
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        $.post(url,data,function(o)
        {
            $("#appendHere").append("<div>"+o+"</div>");
        },'json');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Supposedly, when I'm in the dashboard page this function(xhrgetInsert) has to return value to be appended in the HTML. Unfortunately, it doesn't append anything and as I checked in the chrome console 'response'..it says method doesn't exist. But If I type the method name in the url, it shows the values returned in json format as I specified so.

Same goes for 'xhrInsert()' function as it doesn't return value to be appended. Database connection is perfect as it can insert and select data from db just unable get back the values..
I'm wondering first, why it says the method doesn't exist, and secondly why doesn't return any value?

My 'Dasboard controller making call to dashboard model'

```
public function xhrInsert()
    {
        $this->model->xhrInsert();
    }
    public function xhrgetInsert()
    {
        $this->model->xhrgetInsert();
    }
```

Dashboard model contains mysql queries to the database whcih return values in jason format

```
public function xhrInsert()
    {
        $text =  $_POST['text'];
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO data(text)VALUES(:text)");
        $sql->execute(array(':text'=>$text));
        echo json_encode($text);
    }
    public function xhrgetInsert()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data");
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sth->execute();
        $data = $sth->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Finally, this is my HTML for dashboard

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<form id="randomInsert" action="<?php echo URL;?>dashboard/xhrInsert" method="post">
    <label>Text: </label><input type="text" name="text"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="appendHere"></div>
```

Console Screenshot
[image]

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="base_url" value="<?php echo URL ?>"> // in your html file

after this  var o;
var base_url = $('#base_url').val();
$.get(base_url+'dashboard/xhrgetInsert',function(o)

Try this.

Comment: after this var o; var base_url = $('#base_url').val(); $.get(base_url+'dashboard/xhrgetInsert',function(o) Try this.

Comment: @AmolNavsupe, tried just like your suggection, but still didn't return any value

Comment: do you have skype bro ?

Comment: @AmolNavsupe, unfortunately no..

Comment: please send me console screen shot.

Comment: @AmolNavsupe, I  posted the screenshot in my post above. That was taken under networking tab->response...I see the json ouput echoed as well as the unwanted HTML..probably this HTML is what preventing json values to be passed via my ajax requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109763/discussion-between-amol-navsupe-and-keren).

Comment: Try to use "exit;" or ""die;" after "echo json_encode($data);"    

because as per console you are getting response, but that whole html page and you need json data only, you can put condition for ajax request only.

Comment: @AshishBhagat, I used exit(); after echo json_encode for both functions..however only xhrInsert() works by appending the data returned to the html whereas xhrgetInsert not appending anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function should return the result json data to ajax request so it won't render the whole html page with result.

```
public function xhrInsert(){
    echo $this->model->xhrInsert();
    die;
}
public function xhrgetInsert()
{
    echo $this->model->xhrgetInsert();
    die;
}
```

Model

```
public function xhrInsert()
{
    $text =  $_POST['text'];
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO data(text)VALUES(:text)");
    $sql->execute(array(':text'=>$text));
    return json_encode($text);
}
public function xhrgetInsert()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data");
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();
    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: are you getting data from xhrgetInsert() function? can you share screenshot of console.

Comment: I am getting data in the console for xhrgetInsert if I manually keyed in the funciton in the url tab like: dashboard/xhrgetInsert.But even then its not appended to the html. But if I don't access the function manually, then it says method/function doesn't exist in the console.

Comment: your latest edit works fine for xhrInsert() but not for xhrgetInsert()..I expect that xhrgetInsert to be automatically called every time page is refreshed and that's why I included it inside $(function(){})..Is anything wrong here?

Comment: what is the response from ajax call. can you share me log.. $.get('dashboard/xhrgetInsert',function(o) { console.log(o);

Comment: check the url, is it correct and response code of ajax request. I think you should prepand domain name before url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109771/discussion-between-ashish-bhagat-and-keren).

Comment: @Asish, works now after appended domain name before url..Thanks a lot